# Eclipse "Terminate/Disconnect All" behavior

Tags: java, eclipse

As I was working in a Java project in eclipse, I right-clicked the Console region, and noticed that the Terminate/Disconnect All button was enabled. I was surprised by this, because the application I was working on was threaded. At first I thought this meant not all threads had terminated, but during design, I was meticulous in organization. Naturally, I went back and went through the code to see if anything would cause one of the threads to hang, but I didn't find much regarding this problem.

Afterwards, I wrote a small application to try to diagnose this problem, with more alarming results.

```
public class termtest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Did I terminate?");
    }
}
```

Even this trivial program needs to be terminated via the "Terminate/Disconnect All" item.

[image]

What explains this behavior on eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has terminated as shown by the `<terminated>` message at the top of the console.

When your program terminates Eclipse does not destroy the JVM that was used to run the program immediately as this would clear the console log. Instead it keeps the JVM until you do one of

1. Click the 'Remove Launch', or 'Remove All Terminated Launches' buttons
2. Click the 'Remove All Terminated' context menu
3. Run a new program.

Answer (score 2):

The Java program in this example terminates itself.  The "main" method runs to completion and exits, and that alone causes the JVM process to terminate.  You can see this if you run the program and then go to the Debug view.  You see that the launch's "javaw[.exe]" child line says "terminated".  That represents the exited, i.e. no longer running, JVM.  You can verify that the JVM is gone by using your operating system's favorite utility (e.g. "ps" or Process Explorer" on Windows) to verify that there is no "java[w]" process for your test program.

The launch is purely an in-memory Eclipse object and it is kept in the Debug view so that the Console page associated with the launch can still be inspected by the user.  The output is still, in general, of interest to the user, especially in this kind of case where the program terminates itself, where the user didn't even have to select the "Terminate" button in Eclipse.  The launch still exists in the Debug view, and the associated Console page still exists, but the JVM is exited and gone.

The fact that Eclipse has menu items (in the right-click menu in the Debug view) with "Terminate..." in the menu items' text, is unfortunate and admittedly misleading, since the program has already terminated in this case. The menu item text simply doesn't change whether the launch is in the running state or not.

To get rid of the launch, there's a toolbar button in the Debug view.  Similarly, to get rid of the Console page, there's a toolbar button in the Console view.